# How to root a Samsung Spica

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-spica

How do I go about rooting my Samsung Spica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reference resource site for modders and "cookers" of **Samsung Spica aka i5700** is at Samdroid forum board, [here](http://forum.samdroid.net/#samsung-spica-i5700-android-phone).

It contains all information you need to upgrade your firmware version, [root your phone](http://forum.samdroid.net/f28/spica-v-lk2-02-root-recovery-apps2sd-busybox-wifi-tether-etc-04-15-2010-en-624/), etc.

Comment: Interesting... forum.samdroid.net came up in the Google search but I wouldn't have known it's the main resource. Good answer.

Answer (score 1):

This rooting tutorial is much easier to follow than Samdroid's (it still uses Samdroid's method, but the tutorial is much less terse and have pictures): http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/root-samsung-galaxy-spica-i5700-with-leshaks-kernel/